# How to loop through controls within TabItem

Tags: xaml, grid, scrollviewer

I'd like to loop through the controls within a TabItem.  my xaml is something like

TabControl
  TabItem
    ScrollViewer
     Grid

I have tried

TabItem ti = TabControl.Selected as TabItem

```
foreach (UIElement control in ti)
  ...
```

Which causes an error

Basically I would like to get to the ScrollViewer Content or Grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

First grab the TabItem and declare the ScrollViewer and then get the ScrollViewer Content and declare the Grid as a FrameworkElement

```
TabItem ti = GBtabControl.SelectedItem as TabItem;
ScrollViewer sc = ti.Content as ScrollViewer;
FrameworkElement element = sc.Content as FrameworkElement;
```

Thanks